# Cloning datepicker objects [JQuery]

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an input field that I define as a datepicker through a css class. I now want to clone this input field and have it so the cloned inputs are also datepickers.

After reading from various sources I was lead to believe that the following code should work but it doesn't. I was hoping maybe someone could help me figure out what I was doing wrong :)

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="calendar" />
<input type="button" id="clone" name="clone" value="Clone dates" />
```

And here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.calendar').datepicker();

 $('#clone').click(function()
 {
  $('.calendar:last').clone().append().insertAfter('.calendar:last');
 });

});

</script>
```

So far the input field is duplicated and is inserted at after the last instance but the datepicker doesn't work. I tried passing 'true' to the clone function but it gave me an error saying that *inst wasn't defined*.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
$('.calendar:last').clone(false).removeClass('hasDatepicker').insertAfter('.calendar:last').datepicker();
```

Comment: It clones the input but it doesn't create the datepicker object (it doesn't give an error either which makes it even more confusing)

Comment: Apparently you have to remove the 'hasDatepicker' class before calling datepicker() again.  I've updated the post.

Comment: I played around with the code to understand it a bit more and it seems jQuery uses that class name as a flag to know whether the input has already been initialized. Adding it to a second input keeps the object from becoming a datepicker. Interesting :) Thanks again, I'll go to bed smarter tonight!

Comment: Removing 'hasDatepicker' class is enough.

Comment: To copy the options I did this: `$('.calendar:last').clone(false).removeClass('hasDatepicker').insertAfter('.calendar:last').datepicker($('.calendar:last').datepicker('option', 'all'));`

Answer (score 5):

to bad I can't comment anymore on the answer given above,  but the code still fales! The datepicker shows up at the cloned input element , but uses the selected date value in the original input field and leaves the cloned input field blank .. Any suggestions?

edit:

Using the following code fixed it for me..

```
$('.datum',clone).removeClass("hasDatepicker").attr('id',"").datepicker();
```

( note that I have cloned a wrapper , and am only targeting the 'datum' input field in that wrapper )

After removing the class as suggested above , I also remove id of the cloned input element. It's the same as the original, so that's why I was updating the original input field with the selected date in the datepicker box.

Comment: The `id` is the issue. The `.datepicker()` plugin assigns the element a random id that it then associates with that datapicker object. `Clone()` then retains the id when the element is cloned. It seems to me that `clone()` should probably discard any id that is set, seeing as how `id` is supposed to be unique per document anyways.

Comment: This approach worked for me, except I used removeAttr('id'); Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but all the suggestions above didn't work for me, I came up with an easy solution for this.

First, what is causing the problem:
JQuery assign datepicker to element id. if you are cloning element, then same id might be cloned as well. which jQuery doesn't like. You might end up with either receiving  null reference error or the date being assigned to first input field regardless which input field you click on.

Solution:

1) destroy datepicker
2) assign new unique ids to all input field
3) assign datepicker for each input

Make sure your input is something like this

```
<input type="text" name="ndate[]" id="date1" class="n1datepicker">
```

Before you clone, destroy datepicker

```
$('.n1datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
```

After you clone, add these lines as well

```
var i = 0;
$('.n1datepicker').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("id",'date' + i).datepicker();
    i++;
});
```

and the magic happens

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes and it works.

Before:

```
 $('#clone').click(function()
 {
  $('.calendar:last').clone().append().insertAfter('.calendar:last');
 });
```

After:

```
 $('#clone').click(function()
 {
  $('.calendar:last').clone().append().insertAfter('.calendar:last').attr('id',"");
 });
```