# How to clone jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, inheritance

I need to clone (to inherite) from datepicker jQuery object and override _generatedHTML method.
My code:

```
$.fn.datepickerExt = $.fn.datepicker;
var datepickerOldHTML = $.datepicker._generateHTML;

var datepickerExt = $.extend($.datepicker, {
    _generateHTML: function(inst) {
        var generatedHTML = datepickerOldHTML.apply(this, arguments);
        return "<div style='text-align:center'>header</div>"+generatedHTML;
    }
})
```

But I am not sure that I have different objects $.fn.datepicker and $.fn.datepickerExt..

Link for JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/konstantin/9Rjna/

In this case header need to be added only for datepickerExt...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2358933/901048) helped me with a similar problem last week.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not answer for my question. I need to inherit from existing datepicker (like own plugin)

Answer (score 2):

I come across same problem and after gone through most suggested solution, I got a way out.

```
$('#actions').append($new_row);
$('#actions').find('input.datepicker').removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr('id');
$('#actions').find('button.ui-datepicker-trigger').remove();
$('#actions').find('input.datepicker').unbind();
$('#actions').find('input.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
$('#actions').find('input.datepicker').datepicker(
{
   autoSize:false,
   showOn:'button',
   dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
   weekHeader: 'W',
   showWeek: true,
   firstDay: 0,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   gotoCurrent:true,
   showButtonPanel:true,
   showAnim:'',
   duration:'fast'
}
);
```

After insert the cloned elements (within ID "actions"):

1. Remove every *datepicker* ID so they will be detected otherwise new created *datepicker* will still stick to particular input ID
2. Remove *datepicker* button or it will duplicate on cloned element
3. Unbind *datepicker* (don't know much about this but a must)
4. Destroy *datepicker*
5. Now everything is clean-up, re-initialize *datapicker* event

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to clone the object `$.datepicker` which is an instance of `Datepicker` (Private class in jQuery code). otherwise, you would only do a copy, and you write the same method.

Second, you have to copy the code of `$.fn.datepicker`, because it internally calls the instance of `$.datepicker`.

Code:

```
(function($, window, undefined) {

    $.datepickerExt = jQuery.extend({}, $.datepicker);
    var datepickerOldHTML = $.datepicker._generateHTML;

    $.datepickerExt._generateHTML = function(inst) {
        var generatedHTML = datepickerOldHTML.apply(this, arguments);
        return "<div style='text-align:center'>header</div>" + generatedHTML;
    };

    $.fn.datepickerExt = function(options) {

        /* Verify an empty collection wasn't passed - Fixes #6976 */
        if (!this.length) {
            return this;
        }

        /* Initialise the date picker. */
        if (!$.datepickerExt.initialized) {
            $(document).mousedown($.datepickerExt._checkExternalClick).
            find('body').append($.datepickerExt.dpDiv);
            $.datepickerExt.initialized = true;
        }

        var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        if (typeof options == 'string' && (options == 'isDisabled' || options == 'getDate' || options == 'widget')) return $.datepickerExt['_' + options + 'Datepicker'].apply($.datepickerExt, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
        if (options == 'option' && arguments.length == 2 && typeof arguments[1] == 'string') return $.datepickerExt['_' + options + 'Datepicker'].apply($.datepickerExt, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
        return this.each(function() {
            typeof options == 'string' ? $.datepickerExt['_' + options + 'Datepicker'].
            apply($.datepickerExt, [this].concat(otherArgs)) : $.datepickerExt._attachDatepicker(this, options);
        });
    };

}());
```

[run](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/9Rjna/5/)

Comment: This is not working, as when clicking on some date, original datepicker functionality is called and thus new generate function is not called. Can easily see in sample that when clicking on date header disappears.