# bootstrap datepicker not working if it is cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

By using jquery clone() i am repeating div section of my document. This div also contains bootstrap datepicker. But, cloned div's datepicker won't work. I am using this datepicker https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

**Note:** In code snippet add multiple files in choose file option then only you will see extra datepicker's.

```js
/* Depending on number of documents description box and datepicker will repeat */

$("#docsUpload").change(function() {
   $("#multiShow").empty();                 // removes child elements
    var ele = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
    var result = ele.files;
    var ff = result[0];
    $("#ff").html("<strong> File Name : </strong>"+ ff.name);

    for(var x = 0;x< result.length-1;x++){
       var fle = result[x+1];
       $('#multiShow').append("<div class='row'> <div class='col-sm-3'></div> <div class='col-sm-6'><hr>");
       $('#multiShow').append("&nbsp;<strong> File Name : </strong>"+fle.name);
       $('#multiShow').append("</div><div class='col-sm-3'></div></div>");
       $("#selectAll").clone(true).prop({ id:'thisisid_'+x}).appendTo('#multiShow');
    }
});


/* depending on selection box type of date changes */
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".static").show();  // always display on page load
   $(".period").on('change',function(changeEvent){  //selection box value changed
    // var realId = $(".period").closest("div[id]").attr("id"); //get id
    var realId = $(changeEvent.target).closest("div[id]").attr("id");
    $('#'+realId+' .dateSelector').hide();
    //alert('#'+realId+' '+'.dateSelector');  // display id only show 'selectAll'

     var operation = '.'+this.value;
     $('#'+realId+' '+operation).show();

   });           // on period change
});     // document ready state


/* Format of datepicker */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      format : "MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
      format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
      format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
     format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
      format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
     format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
});
```

```css
.dateSelector{
    display: none;
  }

  h1{
    color:#2F4F4F;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">




<form name="dataSubmit" action="<?php echo base_url('client/store'); ?>"
   method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<hr/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label for="upload">Upload Files : </label>
  <input type="file" name="docs[]" id="docsUpload" class="" multiple="multiple" required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- .row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <span id="ff"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- .row -->


<div id="selectAll">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input type="text" style="margin:5px 0px;" name="describe[]" class="form-control" placeholder="What this file about?" required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- .row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="upload"> Select Type & Date of document below:  </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div> <!-- .row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="form-group">
  <select name="period" class="period">
    <option value="static" selected="selected">Static</option>
    <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="quaterly">Quaterly</option>
    <option value="semester">Semester</option>
    <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- begin : datepicker -->
<div  class="col-sm-4 dateSelector static">
    <div class="input-group date datetimepicker1">
      <input type="text" name="staticDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 dateSelector monthly">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker2">
    <input type="text" name="monthlyDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector quaterly">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<select name="periodQuater[]">
  <option value="first">January - March</option>
  <option value="second">April - June</option>
  <option value="third">July - September</option>
  <option value="fourth">October - December</option>
</select><br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker3">
    <input type="text" name="quaterlyDate" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector semester">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<select name="periodSemester[]">
  <option value="semfirst">April - September </option>
  <option value="semsecond">October - March</option>
</select><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker5">
  <input type="text" name="semesterDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector yearly">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker7">
    <input type="text" name="yearDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector other">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker9">
    <input type="text" name="otherDateF[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div> <br/></div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker10">
    <input type="text" name="otherDateS[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div></div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div> <!-- .row for selector-->
</div> <!-- #selectAll -->

<div id="multiShow"> </div>

<!-- end : datepicker -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Submit </button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Comment: Where did you include `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` and `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css` as your github link said that to include.

Comment: @Curiousdev thanks for adding those files.

Comment: @JoneDotosvky you are always welcome please find my answer for this issue as well

Comment: Can you bound `datetimepicker` to some id instead of class? e.g `$('#someId').datetimepicker({})`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna the original datepicker was with id , i changed it to class. Because i am cloning "selectAll" div this will clone all the id's of original datepicker. Document should have unique id's.

Comment: You know you can change your DOM id's using `attr();`

Comment: See this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358905/cloning-datepicker-objects-jquery

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna thank you for link, i will try the suggested options.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I tried your link but it is not working for me. In my code i am cloning "selectAll" div. This div contains description box and datepicker's. I am just changing selectAll  div's id while cloning, not touching  to datepicker's id. In fact i didn't assign id's to datepickers by thinking that they will duplicate while cloning. If you can some updated code from your side that will be a great help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134438/discussion-between-ataur-rahman-munna-and-jone-dotosvky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#docsUpload").change(function() {
debugger;
   $("#multiShow").empty();                 // removes child elements
    var ele = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
    var result = ele.files;
    var ff = result[0];
    $("#ff").html("<strong> File Name : </strong>"+ ff.name);

    for(var x = 0;x< result.length-1;x++){
       var fle = result[x+1];
       $('#multiShow').append("<div class='row'> <div class='col-sm-3'></div> <div class='col-sm-6'><hr>");
       $('#multiShow').append("&nbsp;<strong> File Name : </strong>"+fle.name);
       $('#multiShow').append("</div><div class='col-sm-3'></div></div>");
       $("#selectAll").clone().prop({ id:'thisisid_'+x}).appendTo('#multiShow');
    }

        $('.dpstatic').datetimepicker({
      format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.dpmonthly').datetimepicker({
      format : "MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.dpquaterly').datetimepicker({
      format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.dpsemester').datetimepicker({
      format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.dpyearly').datetimepicker({
     format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.dpother').datetimepicker({
      format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.dpother').datetimepicker({
     format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });



});


/* depending on selection box type of date changes */
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".static").show();  // always display on page load
   $("body").on('change','.period',function(changeEvent){  //selection box value changed
    // var realId = $(".period").closest("div[id]").attr("id"); //get id
    var realId = $(changeEvent.target).closest("div[id]").attr("id");
    $('#'+realId+' .dateSelector').hide();
    //alert('#'+realId+' '+'.dateSelector');  // display id only show 'selectAll'

     var operation = '.'+this.value;
     $('#'+realId+' '+operation).show();

   });           // on period change
});     // document ready state


$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dpstatic').datetimepicker({
      format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.dpmonthly').datetimepicker({
      format : "MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.dpquaterly').datetimepicker({
      format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.dpsemester').datetimepicker({
      format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.dpyearly').datetimepicker({
     format : 'YYYY'
    });
    $('.dpother').datetimepicker({
      format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });
    $('.dpother').datetimepicker({
     format : "DD/MM/YYYY"
    });

});
```

```css
  .dateSelector{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<div class="container-fluid">

<form name="dataSubmit" action="<?php echo base_url('client/store'); ?>"
   method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<hr/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label for="upload">Upload Files : </label>
  <input type="file" name="docs[]" id="docsUpload" class="" multiple="multiple" required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- .row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <span id="ff"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- .row -->


<div id="selectAll">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input type="text" style="margin:5px 0px;" name="describe[]" class="form-control" placeholder="What this file about?" required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- .row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="upload"> Select Type & Date of document below:  </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div> <!-- .row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="form-group">
  <select name="period" class="period">
    <option value="static" selected="selected">Static</option>
    <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="quaterly">Quaterly</option>
    <option value="semester">Semester</option>
    <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- begin : datepicker -->
<div  class="col-sm-4 dateSelector static">
    <div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpstatic">
      <input type="text" name="staticDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 dateSelector monthly">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpmonthly">
    <input type="text" name="monthlyDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector quaterly">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<select name="periodQuater[]">
  <option value="first">January - March</option>
  <option value="second">April - June</option>
  <option value="third">July - September</option>
  <option value="fourth">October - December</option>
</select><br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpquaterly">
    <input type="text" name="quaterlyDate" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector semester">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<select name="periodSemester[]">
  <option value="semfirst">April - September </option>
  <option value="semsecond">October - March</option>
</select><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpsemester">
  <input type="text" name="semesterDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector yearly">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpyearly">
    <input type="text" name="yearDate[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dateSelector other">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpother">
    <input type="text" name="otherDateF[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div> <br/></div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker dpother">
    <input type="text" name="otherDateS[]" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div></div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div> <!-- .row for selector-->
</div> <!-- #selectAll -->

<div id="multiShow"> </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Submit </button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Run the snippet to check what changes i have made compare to original code.

Changes I have made:

(1) As point out by Curiousdev

- remove true from clone()
- in period repeat all the date formats

(2) This is very important,

- Add unique class element to each calendar types. Checkout JSFiddle and search for dpstatic , dpmonthly, dpquaterly, dpsemester, dpyearly, dpother. Without adding this elements calendar will not show respective date formats and some time even calendar wont appear.

For fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rv285q8x/

Thank you @Curiousdev and @Ataur Rahman Munna  for valuable information and help.

Answer (score 1):

After cloning date picker to `DOM` you must have to do following things to bind date-picker to the newly created elements i recommend to apply same `class` to all datepicker `inputs` and than do same as follow to bind datepicker.

You can also read this [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) for more information

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update');
```

Comment: I added 'datepickerForAll' class to all input boxes of dates and $(' .datepickerForAll').datepicker('update'); in script. Still it is not working. I hope you meant that only.

Comment: can you please share some code in which way you are cloning this datepicker so it would be easier to figure where thing's going wrong ?

Comment: all the code is in above snippets. I added comments in javascript section to understand it more clearly. What above code does is depending on number of documents selected description box and datepicker gets repeated. If you look at HTML code you can understand that description box and all datepicker are present in one id called "selectAll". This "selectAll" is cloned and its id is changed. Let me know if you want any further clarification.

Comment: Hoofff finally got a solution please find [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kz5dyp9/6/) just replace `clone(true)` to `clone()` , `.period` on change event has been modified for dynamically created element and after clone html `$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(` call this datepicker method for dynamically cloned element

Comment: thank you for your replay. I checked your solution . There is some problem. In all input boxes only static date type is showing & after cloning also only static option is coming up. I tried myself some option and finally able to come at right solution for me.  Check my answer for final solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should simply copy and paste my code.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
    })
</script>

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: This does work i know, but answer should be w.r.t above question.